# Unable to launch my windows App in windows 10 machine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mfc, frameworks

i have some problem with windows 10 machine, my Windows application is developed using C#,C++,mfc and winForms. So currently i am using win 7 machine and i am able to launch my App there is no issues with this machine.

But in win 10 while Double clicking on my .exe it's not opened and did not get any error msg...i don't know how can i trace this thing. here what i observed is while comparing .net frameworks in win 7 and 10 machines in win 7 i have .net framework 3.5(include 2.0 and 3.0) but in win 10 i have .net framework 4 onwards so i just installed framework 3.5(include 2.0 and 3.0) it's working fine.

then i opened .csproj xml files there is a line called `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` it is targeting v4.0 and here we have some lines which are pointing to references

```
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Design" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Remoting" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
```

so, here i have some issues:

I have some more references which are pointing to 2.0 and 3.0 as well,

can i change 2.0,3.0 and 3.5 to 4.0?
those references will support in 4.0?

or

any solution to work my app in win 10?

```
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
  <Install>false</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
  <Visible>False</Visible>
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
  <Install>true</Install>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

The above one is in framework 3.5 it should be in 4.0 or  nothing?

if it should be in .net framework 4.0, how can i replace those things?

help me out this.

Thanks in advance.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Why is this tagged MFC ?

Comment: i used in my application.

Comment: I don't know what i missed in my app but if i have 3.5 framework it is working otherwise it's not working.

Comment: If you use winForms it seems normal that you need to have the corresponding .net framework installed.